# Hibernate - AnnotationConfiguration deprecated

Tags: hibernate, annotations, deprecated

I am using Hibernate in version 3.6.0 and the AnnotationConfiguration is marked as deprecated.

Here is the the line in my HibernateUtil.java class:

```
sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure("/hib.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

What's the replacement for AnnotationConfiguration?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"All functionality has been moved to Configuration":
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration.html

And here is Configuration:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html

Comment: Why, then, does the application not start up with Configuration, but gives a MappingException: An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class=... ?

Comment: That's the same error that I get when trying to use this with Hiberate 4.0.1

Answer (score 5):

Just do this

```
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
```

and then change your code for this

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("/hib.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this code:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.configure();
ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
configuration.getProperties()).build();

sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

Answer (score 1):

yes it is working for me-

```
Configuration cfg=new Configuration();
    cfg.configure();

    ServiceRegistry serviceregistry=new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(cfg.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();


    Session session=cfg.configure().buildSessionFactory(serviceregistry).openSession();
```