# Annotations are deprecated in Hibernate problem

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations, slf4j

I'm trying to code some hibernate examples, and I've found this :

```
AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration();
```

And Eclipse is saying : **Deprecated**

Also when I run the Application, I get this :

> SLF4J: slf4j-api 1.6.x (or later) is
>   incompatible with this binding.
>
> SLF4J: Your binding is version 1.5.5
>   or earlier.
>
> SLF4J: Upgrade your binding to version
>   1.6.x. or 2.0.x

I've used this two packages of Hibernate :

`hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA` & `hibernate-distribution-3.6.5.Final-dist`

How can Solve this thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question regard the post [Hibernate - AnnotationConfiguration deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942880/hibernate-annotationconfiguration-deprecated)

The SLF4J is not related to this I guess, try to investigate which libraries are included into your project, and put the right SLF4J version in place. Consider [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-log4j-in-hibernate-project/) for more information e.g.

Best regards.