# Hibernate 3.6.8 + Annotated POJOs + Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hibernate - AnnotationConfiguration deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942880/hibernate-annotationconfiguration-deprecated)

In version 3.2 of Hibernate, I could configure hibernate and programmatically add the annotated classes through the Class AnnotationConfiguration.

But in a recent project, I am trying to use version 3.6, and just can not make it work.

Someone have a updated example for this?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In newer Hibernate versions, AnnotationConfiguration has been deprecated in favor of Configuration.

You can use the Configuration's

> addAnnotatedClass(Object)

method with the same effect you had in 3.2 and below, as you can see in this post:

[Hibernate - AnnotationConfiguration deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942880/hibernate-annotationconfiguration-deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `new Configuration().addAnnotatedClass(annotatedClass)`